# How to measure dynamodb perfomance?

Tags: performance, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, dynamo-local

Is there some convenient way to measure dynamodb performance? Preferable locally   in unit tests. The aim is to avoid accidentally doing full table scans.

Comment: Just inspect your code for calls to `.scan`

Comment: But lets say I want to compare the speed of a query using .scan to one using .findByKeys (or two different scan for that matter). Maybe I already know the answer in theory but lets say I want know the answer to be able to prove it in practice?

Comment: My best ideas are return the consumed capacity in your queries, then you can compare how efficient two queries are. As for latency, you probably just have profile the calls, but this really has to be done in production because local-dynamodb will give different results than real dynamoDB.